# Why does Laravel 5 ignore catch block?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I put an error at that line

```
$user = $account->users->fill($this->getUserData($request));
```

but the catch block never gets called. Getting `Symfony\FatalErrorException` instead.

```
public function saveAccount($request, $listener){ 

    $this->uploadFile($request, $listener);  

    DB::beginTransaction();

    try {            
        $account = $this->update($this->getAccountData($request), $request->id);
        $user = $account->users->fill($this->getUserData($request));
        $user->push();
        DB::commit();
        return $listener->doRedirect(null, trans('account.success'));
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $this->rollBackUpload($rl,$ml);
        DB::rollBack();
        return $listener->doRedirect('error', trans('account.error'));
    }
}
```

Comment: Just code without any explanation?

Comment: Sorry sectus, i hit enter before completing the question.

Comment: Could it be that your exception is actually triggered by the catch block ?

Comment: @mika what?? How come i'm not getting a redirect ?

Comment: If your exception is thrown, say, by your rollBackUpload, then you are out in the blue: it is not catched at all. The first exception that has been thrown  (and caused the catch to be executed) will be ignored, and the newly generated exception will be propagated. Then, in your example, none of the redirect is ever executed.

Comment: Thanks @mika according to the docs, i can catch the error in App/Exception/Handler.php http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/errors#handling-errors

Comment: Did you put a var_dump at the beginning of the catch block ? If an exception is thrown in the try block, then catch will be executed. It does not depend on the framework. It's a PHP language feature. Anyway, if you get to go with the global error handler, then I guess you are doing fine...

Comment: Here's the thing @mika i deliberately changed the relation user to users $user = $account->users->fill($this->getUserData($request)); and i get Symfony\FatalException fill can not be called on null but the catch never get called.

Answer (score 1):

Doing the following works for me:
In App/Exception/Handler.php
http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/errors#handling-errors

```
  public function render($request, Exception $e){

    if ($e instanceof FatalErrorException)
    { 
       $errorsEx = explode("\n", $e->getMessage());
       return redirect()->route('route')->with('errorsEx', $errorsEx);
    }

    return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```